# function to transfer eth in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I ussing this function to transfer, but it working with `value  0 wei`

```
function send(address _from, address _to) public payable {
    require(msg.sender > 0);
    _from.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Payment( _from, _to, msg.value);
}
```

How can I implement this with another wei value?

Comment: This function accepts any non-zero amount of ether and transfers that ether to `_from`. Is that what you wanted? If not, what _did_ you want?

Comment: I want a specific number as a transaction with 1 ETH.  how do I get that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I want to make a transaction with the returned result is not `value 0 wei`

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the returned result." If you send 1 ether to this function, 1 ether will be transferred to the address `_from`.

Comment: changed msg.value to 1 ether and got the error `transact to Pay.send errored: VM error: revert.The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.`

Comment: I think you're quite confused. Maybe start here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/.

Comment: I know. Maybe I need to reread the knowledge you sent me. Thank you so much, bro

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to send the ether to `_to` then you should do:

```
function send(address _from, address _to) public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    _to.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Payment( _from, _to, msg.value);
}
```

This will allows any value bigger than zero, if as in your comments you want only values of exactly 1 ETH, you should do:

```
function send(address _from, address _to) public payable {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    _to.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Payment( _from, _to, msg.value);
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

In your require statement, you should require, that `msg.value` is greater then 0.

```
function send(address _from, address _to) public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0); //This will revert if msg.value will be 0
    _from.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Payment( _from, _to, msg.value);
}
```

Comment: I did your way and got the status on remix: `Transaction mined but execution failed`

Comment: Maybe your gasLimit is too low. Try to put higer number.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xcMy729.png Like this -> works. Btw... `_from.transfer(msg.value)` means, that `_from` address will recieve `msg.value`. And it will recieve from `msg.sender` (the one, that executes the transcaction).What i am trying to say is, that usually transfer looks like this: `_to.transfer(msg.value)`

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. I was wrong. I will try your way again

Comment: Good. You should mark anwser as solution, if it works for you.